# Export React Native Views as embeddable SDK

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sdk

I want to develop a React Native Application (View) and embed this into existing Apps (native, hybrid, ...) as some kind of sdk (let's call it "react-native-sdk"). In addition to that I want to hide implementational details of this "react-native-sdk", which prevents doing it [the easy way](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html).

I also need to achieve simple communication between the host-app and the "react-native-sdk" (passing parameters and calling a callback from within the sdk). Both Android and iOS is relevant for me.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: are you able to achieve react native views as embeddable SDK? I need same kind of functionality

Comment: No, i didn't. We ended up developing a native SDK (no react-native) :(